# LO Writer: Table border disappear upon PDF export

Tags: libreoffice

I have a table in a Writer document. In the document the table borders are visible.

The problem is when i export the document as a PDF file. The borders disappear.

Is it possible to change this behaviour?

Comment: I managed to get the table border printed onto the PDF file. In case someone else ends up having the same problem, here's what I did.

I selected the columns in the table. Then clicked on the borders button from the toolbar that appears once you select the table. Selected a border and then exported the PDF.

Answer (score 1):

The Writer edit window shows a thin gray border even if the table has no borders to help your editing. You can go to File -> Print Preview to see the document as it will look like when it comes to PDF export or printing.